# Java, EMF + OCL Diagnotician can't handle duplicate id

Tags: java, validation, emf, ocl

i have an EMF model where some objects contain IDs, and others don't. The id attribute is configured like this:

[image]

I use the java Diagnostician to check if any of the OCL Constraints are violated:

```
protected Diagnostic validateModel(EObject modelRoot) {
    return Diagnostician.INSTANCE.validate(modelRoot);
}
```

Which works just fine in most cases. But as soon as there are duplicate Ids the Validator throws a ClassCastException, where he tries to cast one of the two objects to the type of the other. What can i do to aviod this? Would an OCL constraint that checks for duplicate Ids help somehow?

Comment: Okay, i managed to find what exactly causes the issue. if there is a proxy that points towards a duplicate id, the diagnostican gets confused. Will upload MWE as soon as i get around to it